# Github: remove certain files from a comparison?

Tags: github

I'm making a pull request with a lot of changes. Most of the changes, however, are just data, and not code. Binary files, test data, etc. Therefore it's not meaningful or necessary for these files to be seen in the list of changes seen when viewing the differences between master and what I'm merging.

Is there any way to choose only a subset of files to be displayed in the comparison, rather than all?

Comment: It would be a massive security flaw in GitHub if that were possible.

Comment: I don't mean to make them completely invisible; I simply mean the ability to choose which specific files you want to view when looking at a comparison. Obviously you can choose which ever files to view (all of them, if you wanted). Seeing 50,000 lines of irrelevant text in a comparison does not contribute to good security.

Answer (score 0):

The only way would be if they are not part of the pull request.
That might be possible if you did two branches:

- one with the data and the fixes
- one with only the fixes

Use the second for the pull request.